# File Import to mySQLi - not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been stuck trying to import an csv into SQL for 3, coming on 4 days now.

I have read **ALL** stack overflow answers for importing CSV into mySQLi, and none have worked as of yet - so this is not a duplicate. Bit's of my code is made up from different posts on here and on the internet but nothing quite works.

Things I do know:
- My SQL connection is fine

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mattsDB"; 

// Create connection 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) { 
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } 


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ('hi.csv') 
INTO TABLE names 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(firstname);

?>
```

I've also fiddled with the last section, with something like this:

```
$query = <<<eof
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ('hi.csv') 
INTO TABLE names 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(firstname) 
eof;
```

It's getting to the point where I'm begging for someone's help... Am I doing something blatently wrong? Edit: I'm aware you can do this manually in SQL, but I need to do it through code.

Comment: What is the current error message/result?  Are you aware that you are specifying a single column only (firstname) as input?  Can you show us the first 3-4 lines from your CSV file?

Comment: The error message is "unexpected T_string" on the LOAD DATA line. This is only a test, that's why I only have one column. It's just three rows saying "hi", "hi2" and "hi3".

Comment: This strikes me as a PHP problem, rather than a MySQL one.  But, since I don't know/use PHP regularly I can't offer any advice.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thank you for trying to assist anyway - I appreciate it.

Comment: The advice I would give you is to just get your PHP working with _any_ query.  Then, substitute in your `LOAD DATA` command, and it should work.  I don't see any obvious problems with how you are calling `LOAD DATA`, though you can always try running it directly on MySQL first.

Comment: If this is all the code you have, then you are missing `conn.mysqli_query($query)`. See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php.

Comment: you have a text block in the middle of the php script, that would explain the error. the 2nd block is right, but you still have to actually run the query

Answer (score 0):

I've once spent hours making a similar query working. The problem was PHP is making a mess of quotes and slashes. In the end I got it working by using the absolute pathname for the file and some weird combination for `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY`:

```
$file=str_replace('\\','\\\\',$absolute_file_path);

//chr(34) = double quote
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '".chr(34)."'
```

I ended up with this query:

```
<?php
$query=
    "
    LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file."'        //# note that the filename is also quoted
    INTO TABLE `table`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '".chr(34)."'
    ESCAPED BY ''
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ";
```

I also suggest that you read up about [LOCAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), as there is also the possibility mysql can't find the file.